# Direct APA citation in LaTeX

Tags: citing, apa-style

I am writing a paper and the citation in `APA` format. I am using `\cite{authoryear}` for the indirect citation e.g.
*Paraphrased summary of the ideas (lastNameofAuthor1, year)*

What should I do for a direct citation according to lastNameofAuthor1(year) paraphrased idea?

Please don't ask me to follow the first format, if you don't know the workaround. sometimes it is natural to write ideas directly quoting the author.

Comment: Since you haven't given any indication what you are using for your citations, it's difficult to tell, but  `natbib`, `apacite`, and `biblatex` all provide ways of doing both type of citation.  So check the documentation for whatever package you are using to find which ones to use.  See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793) for an overview.  Given the vagueness of your question, I'm voting to close it as a duplicate of this.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?